# Displays each char that appears in char[] array more than the specified char // Java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to write a method in Java that will take `(char[] abc,char x)` as parameters.

It should :

a)check whether the specified character appears in the array and how many times it appears in the array.
b)Display each character that appears in a given array of chars for more than the specified number of characters.

**Example for method parameters**

```
char[] abc={'a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','x'};

char x='x';
```

All help & tips are welcome !

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having problems with? We're not going to just do your homework for you

Comment: Take it easy,first of all it's not like I didnt tried,I made a counter so I can count how many times that char appears in array. My problem is : How to take first 'a',count it,and not repeat for rest of  'a'...idk I stucked .

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
public static void countChar(char[] abc, char x){
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(char c: abc){
        if(map.containsKey(c))
            map.put(c,map.get(c)+1);
        else
            map.put(c,1);
    }

    if(map.get(x)!=null){
        int count = map.get(x);
        System.out.println(x + " exists " + count + " times in char array!");
        for(char c: map.keySet()){
            if(map.get(c)>count)
                System.out.println(c);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println(x + " does not exist in char array!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that solves the problem but you didn't resolve part (a) first. 
1. Does it exist? If yes how many times?
2. If yes, then which characters appeared more. 

I still upvoted your question, but please do make those edits.

Comment: @HarisNadeem edited the answer to cover both the cases.